# How can I change the style of highlighted texts in the browser search result?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

In major browsers, if I press `Ctrl-F` and input a phrase, the corresponding text in the webpage will be highlighted. I'm wondering if there is a way to customize the style of the highlighted text.

[image: screenshot]

e.g. Is it possible to change the color of `world` to red, in the screenshot?

UPDATE:

`::selection` does not work, as the text is not selected unless I close the search dialog. See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results from the *Find function* cannot be changed - this is the default User agent styling and I don't think there is any standard attribute that allows you to do it.

*What you can do* is to set it up for the browser you use, or just as much as set up the text selection color.

**Browser Settings**

If you want just to modify the style for a specific browser - see what you can do for:

1. *Firefox* - add `ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention` with value as the color you need in `about:config`
2. *Chrome* - you don't have any hidden settings like Firefox has and there is no way to change it AFAIK.

*Note that the default styles may pick up the find highlight color from the OS theme too.*

**Text Selection**

However, there is a way for styling *text selection* - you can use the [*`selection` psuedo element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) - see demo below:

```css
.custom::selection {
  background: red; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
.custom::-moz-selection {
  background: red; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

```html
<div class="custom"> This is some text</div>
<div>More text here</div>
```

Comment: `::selection` does not work if I don't close the search dialog. I have added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: so is there any `::-webkit-search-result`-like stuff for the highlighted text?

Answer (score 1):

Use `::selection`, like:

```
/* For other Browsers */    
::selection {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

/* For Firefox */
::-moz-selection {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

::selection {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi unde reprehenderit voluptas! Deserunt ducimus reiciendis necessitatibus adipisci obcaecati iste alias voluptate ratione ut at exercitationem, eum, dicta, excepturi eius suscipit.</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `::selection` does not work if I don't close the search dialog. I have added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: @xmcp No you can't really change that color. It is browser specific.